# how to see all directory sizes named invoices in a bash script

Tags: bash, find, du

I have a list of directories and was wondering if there was a bash script to do maybe a for loop to go through and enter `du -h` at the last directory (`/something/something/invoices`). Or is there a better command to do than: `find / -type d -name "/something/something/invoices" -ls`
that would include the invoices directory sizes.

Thank you and hope to hear from someone.

Comment: `du -h /*/*/invoices`?

Comment: Please add your desired output to your question (no comment here).

Answer (score 0):

If `invoices` can appear on any depth in the subtree, use `find`'s `-exec` option:

```sh
find / -type d -name invoices -exec du -h {} \;
```

```
3,5M    /here/there/invoices
1,6M    /somewhere/else/invoices
560K    /nested/really/really/really/deep/invoices
:
```